# Accessing images saved by Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, filesystems

I'm writing a folder watcher, which I have had working on some devices, but not all devices seem to save to the same location. What I'm trying to do is allow users to save an image from a web app, using Chrome, which the presence of a new file should then kick off another process.

On a Samsung Galaxy tablet, images are saving to /mnt/sdcard/Download/ and I have no problems monitoring this folder.

But on a Samsung Galaxy III phone, they are going here /storage/sdcard0/android/data/com.android.chrome/files/download
I'm having permissions issues monitoring this folder.

So I guess my question is two fold. Is there a simpler way of detecting where these images get saved to? I am using INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, but that doesn't get me there for the phone.

If there is an issue with accessing the folder on the phone, what can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hard coding the path following the External_Content_URI.

```
final String protectedpathToWatch = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/Download/";
```

Then to read that path, I had to add special permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DEVELOPMENT_TOOLS"/>
```

This is apparently due to a security bug that affects Chrome. Saving a image generated from a canvas gets stored in its system directory, the same location as cookies. Until they change this behavior, one would need to use special permissions to obtain access to those downloads.